# Unexplained increase of reputation when accepting an answer

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I have just accepted an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6915828/cannot-link-to-lib-file-after-upgrading-to-vs10/7313304#7313304). Afterwards I noted that my rep had increased by 2, and I remember that you are given that every time you accept an answer. However, when I looked at the *Reputation* tab of my user info pages, the `+2` do not show up.

I suppose this is a bug?

Comment: The reputation tab may be cached for up to 5 minutes in various cases...are you still seeing this?

Comment: @Nick: Thanks. I guess I need more patience. `:-x`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is there from what I see:

```
+2   10 mins ago    accepted    Cannot link to lib file after upgrading to VS10
```

and it shows up on your graph, too.

So, you definitely got credit for it, but there could be a problem with displaying it in your own profile.

Comment: +1 because [I can see it as well](http://i.stack.imgur.com/S4hOD.png).

Comment: @DMA Thanks for preparing the graphic.

Comment: @DMA: Yeah, it's there now. I guess I wasn't patient enough. Thanks for looking into this and sorry for wasting your time!